# How to make ant-design Drawer component width responsive

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using ant design drawer component and style component. It seems the I can set a fixed width with width props. ButI can't make it responsive.

```
<Drawer
   width={500}
   placement="right"
   closable={true}
   onClose={this.props.handleDrawer}
   visible={this.props.visible}
>
```

Comment: try `width="50%"` or something similar

Comment: I tried that, again I need 70/80% for mobile!

Comment: and `width="80%"` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An actual solution would be to use an expression.

Like `const isMobile = true //do a match on something there`

And use that expression to render a conditional percent since attribute are just javascript you could do something like.

`width={isMobile ? "80%" : "40%"}`

Comment: prefer using css for better performance. This adds a resize-observer, and it will start flooding your logs (sentry) with false positives.

Answer (score 6):

In my case this one-liner would be the simplest solution:

`width={window.innerWidth > 900 ? 800 : window.innerWidth - 100}`

Comment: This is the simplest solution! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying a fixed width you should use `className` to assign a css class, which you then need to adjust to be responsive in the according .less file. Something like:

```
.my-drawer {
    width: 50%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen-md) {
    .my-drawer {
        width: 70%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this would work since the drawer has an inline width.

Comment: Ideally this is the best solution for performance. (handled by CSS).
To answer Baldrani's point, we can use !important, to take precedence over the inline width;

Answer (score 2):

If you came here looking for the angular version, here's an idea:

In your html file where you are using `<nz-drawer>`, you can simply add [nzWidth]="'fit-content'", like so

```
<nz-drawer
  [nzWidth]="'fit-content'"
```

And from there, you can use `[ngClass]` in the `*nzDrawerContent` reference, like so:

```
<nz-drawer
  [nzWidth]="'fit-content'">
  <div *nzDrawerContent [ngClass.xl]="'xlClass'" [ngClass.xs]="'xsClass'">
```

In your scss/css file you can then give those classes properties, such as `.xlClass{width: 90px}` for example.

Answer (score 1):

So baciscally ther's no max-witdh option in AntD so you have two ways to achieve this,

First with ternary condition:

```
width={window.innerWidth > 1200 ? 800 : 'auto'}
```

second:

```
width={80%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `global.window.innerWidth` to get the width of the device and set it to your drawer width

```
const fullWidth = global.window.innerWidth

<Drawer
   width={fullWidth}
   placement="right"
   closable={true}
   onClose={this.props.handleDrawer}
   visible={this.props.visible}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, you must have found the solution by now, but considering to answer this because I have recently encountered the same problem and open to any rectification or labelled it as 'spaghetti code'.

You can get the innerWidth of your screen and customize your drawer accordingly. This will store your screen width in viewportWidth variable

```
if(typeof(window.innerWidth)!='undefined'){
    this.state.viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Now style your Drawer accordingly. You can set your breakpoints however you want. 700 is safe :

```
<Drawer
    title="Your Drawer Title"
    width={this.state.viewportWidth>700 ? 200 : 180}
    placement="left"
    closable={false}
    onClose={this.onClose}
    visible={this.state.visible}
>
```

Also. Don't forget this might not work for IE or older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Drawer
  className="my-drawer"
  ...
```

```css
.my-drawer.ant-drawer-open {
  // width: 100% !important; // mask: false
  > .ant-drawer-content-wrapper {
    width: 30% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .my-drawer.ant-drawer-open {
    > .ant-drawer-content-wrapper {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `className` for `Drawer` - `className={styles.customDrawer}` and do like this (change `right` to what you have set for `placement` option):

```
.customDrawer {
  width: 260px!important;
  right: 0!important;
  position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 340px) {
  .customDrawer {
    width: 320px!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: avoid using !important. It may work for small projects, but as you grow. It will start overlapping with more complex interactions